# Reading XML from isolated storage to ListBox

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I have this code to read XML file from isolated storage to ListBox:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("People2.xml", FileMode.Open, isoStore))
            {
                XDocument loadedCustomData = XDocument.Load(isoStream);
                var filteredData = from c in loadedCustomData.Descendants("person")
                                   select new Person()
                                   {
                                       Name = c.Attribute("name").Value,
                                       Beneficiary = c.Attribute("beneficiary").Value,
                                       Price = c.Attribute("price").Value,
                                       Deadline = c.Attribute("deadline").Value,
                                       Index = c.Attribute("index").Value,
                                       Description = c.Attribute("description").Value

                                   };

                listBox.ItemsSource = filteredData;
            }
        }
```

But when I execute it against this XML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<people>
    <person id="2"
            name="przyklad"
            price="850"
            deadline="22.10.12"
            beneficiary="asdasd"
            description="xxx" />
</people>
```

I have this error:

```
NullReferenceException
```

In this code fragment:

```
select new Person()
                               {
                                   Name = c.Attribute("name").Value,
                                   Beneficiary = c.Attribute("beneficiary").Value,
                                   Price = c.Attribute("price").Value,
                                   Deadline = c.Attribute("deadline").Value,
                                   Index = c.Attribute("index").Value,
                                   Description = c.Attribute("description").Value

                               };
```

Do you know what can help?

Comment: Show the XML file structure, please.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<people>
<person id="2" name="przyklad" price="850" deadline="22.10.12" beneficiary="asdasd" description="xxx" />
</people>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<people>
    <person id="2" name="przyklad" price="850" deadline="22.10.12" beneficiary="asdasd" description="xxx" />
</people>
```

There is no `index` attribute on your XML, so following line is the reason of you exception:

```
Index = c.Attribute("index").Value
```

Comment: Oh man, thanks. Problem solved. A po naszemu dzięki za pomoc ;) moja nieuwaga :)